# Can I use the sharp library on an image on an external host?

Tags: node.js, sharp

I have a code.

```
sharp('https://external-image.jpeg')
    .resize(100, 100)
    .toFile('path_to_my_folder');
```

This does not work. But if I download this image, and try to resize it:

```
sharp('path_to_local_img')
    .resize(100, 100)
    .toFile('path_to_my_folder');
```

Sharp works as it should.

There is some way to avoid downloading images for sharp?

Comment: How could it work without the image data? Or are you asking if it can get that data automatically?

Comment: Yep, Could I somehow transfer all the necessary data about the image for the sharp without downloading the image?

Comment: You can't resize an image without the image. It says it takes filesystem, stream, or buffer input--you obviously need the data; where that data lives/how it's retrieved appears to be up to you.